# Domain as fallback to subdomains in apache

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have a few subdomains to my domains and I want the domain to work as a fallback if the user writes the wrong subdomain.
These subdomains works:
files.myadomain.com, phpmyadmin.mydomain.com and server.mydmomain.com

And the other domains/subdomains return a HTTP 500 error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

And if I enter a subdomain that doesn't exist I end up in /var/www/

Here is the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName files.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rcane/files.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rcane/media.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rcane/wordpress.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myml.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/johan/ayml/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName johan.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/johan/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sqlbuddy.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sqlbuddy/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rcane/mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the error log with LogLevel debug:

```
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 01.254.002.30] r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 01.254.002.30] redirected from r->uri = /
[Sat Apr 28 13:42:24 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 01.254.002.30] Zlib: Compressed 627 to 379 : URL /rcane/server.mydomain.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a problem with your last [`ServerName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) directive. The syntax should be

> **ServerName** `fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]`

Try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I have updated the config above and the weird thing is that files.myadomain.com, phpmyadmin.mydomain.com and server.mydmomain.com works

Comment: @Patrik Strange. You don't have RewriteRules in the configs that fail or in .htaccess in the target directories that could lead to infinite modifications of the URL?

Comment: Yeah... I just remember that and removed it and hey presto, success. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Well, Apache can be quite a puzzle:)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to remove this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ rcane/server.mydomain.com/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ rcane/server.mydomain.com/
```